# How can I \label \subsection in \intertext inside flalign? (LATEX)

Tags: latex

I have one `flalign` environment, so columns are aligned same way whole page. I need `\subsection`s inside this `flalign`, so I used `\intertext`. And I need `\label` these `\subsection`s. And thats where I failed. It `\label` first equation after `\subsection` but not `\subsection` itself or error occurs.

Image:

[image: screenshot]

When I tried to use more `flalign` environments and place subsections between them they were not aligned same way and it looked terible.

Thanks for help.

```latex
\begin{flalign}
   &\text{Značení: } &&X\sim \text{Exp($\lambda$)} &&
   \\
   &\text{Parametry: } &&\lambda > 0 &&
   \\
   &\text{Nosič: } &&X \in (0,\infty) &&
   \\
   &\text{Hustota: } &&f(x)= 
   \begin{cases}
      \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x>0
      \\
      0 & x\leq 0
   \end{cases}
   \\
   &\text{Distribuční funkce: } &&F(x)=
   \begin{cases}
      1-e^{-\lambda x} & x>0
      \\
      0 & x\leq 0
   \end{cases} &&
   \\
   &\text{Střední hodnota: } && \E X = \frac{1}{\lambda} &&
   \\
   &\text{Rozptyl: } && \var X = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} &&
   \\
\intertext{\subsection{Weibullovo rozdělení}}\label{priloha:weibdist}
   &\text{Značení: } &&X\sim \text{Weib($\alpha$, $\beta$)}&&
   \\
   &\text{Parametry: } &&\text{$\alpha$, $\beta>0$}&&
   \\
   &\text{Nosič: } &&X \in \langle 0,\infty)&&
   \\
   &\text{Hustota: } &&f(x)=
   \begin{cases}
      \alpha \beta^\alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{-(\beta x)^\alpha} & x\geq 0
      \\
      0 & x< 0
   \end{cases}&&
   \\
   &\text{Distribuční funkce: } &&F(x)=
   \begin{cases}
      1-e^{-(\beta x)^\alpha} & x\geq 0
      \\
      0 & x< 0
   \end{cases}
   \\
   &\text{Střední hodnota: } &&\E X = \frac{1}{\beta} \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)
   \\
   &\text{Rozptyl: } &&\var X = \frac{1}{\beta^2} \left\lbrace\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)-\left[\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\right]^2\right\rbrace
   \\
\intertext{\subsection{Gama rozdělení}}\label{priloha:gammadist}
   &\text{Značení: } &&X\sim \Gamma(\alpha,\;\beta)&&
   \\
   &\text{Parametry: } &&\alpha,\; \beta > 0
   \\
   &\text{Nosič: } &&X \in (0,\infty)
   \\
   &\text{Hustota: } &&f(x)=
   \begin{cases}
      \frac{\alpha^\beta}{\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\beta-1}e^{-\alpha x} & x>0
      \\
      0 & x\leq 0
   \end{cases}
   \\
   &\text{Střední hodnota: } && \E X = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}
   \\
   &\text{Rozptyl: } && \var X = \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2}
\end{flalign}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I will try it under my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the images you show, I would suggest to use a tabular with a fixed width instead. This will allow you to break for things like subsections:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\subsection{First part}

\noindent%
{%
\abovedisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\belowdisplayskip=-.5\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.3\textwidth}@{}p{.7\textwidth}@{}}
First equation: & \begin{equation} a+b+c=d \end{equation}\\
Second equation: & \begin{equation} a+b+c=d \end{equation}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\subsection{Second part}
\label{sub:1}

\noindent%
{%
\abovedisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\belowdisplayskip=-.5\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{.3\textwidth}@{}m{.7\textwidth}@{}}
Next equation: & \begin{equation} a+b+c+45867+ddlk=d \end{equation}\\
Another equation: & \begin{equation} a+b+c+sdfsdf+565=d \end{equation}\\
\end{tabular}
}

Here alignment is working, but labeling not. Second part is \ref{sub:1}. It referes to 3th equation instead of subsection.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to use tabular, but it always put my table centered to the middle of the page, not to the left side. This is somehow on the left, so it is perfectly fine.